# error when entering values by Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, function

I want to enter a value by console in Oracle 10g with PL SQL. I am using the web based interface and not the SQL*.
The program is like this:

```
DECLARE
      v_desc VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    v_desc:=show_desc(&sv_cnumber);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_desc);
END;
```

and the function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION show_desc
    (i_course_id course.course_id%TYPE)
RETURN varchar2
AS
        v_desc varchar2(50);
BEGIN
SELECT description
    INTO v_desc
    FROM courses
WHERE course_id=i_course_id;
RETURN v_desc;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
    RETURN('no description found');
END;
```

when I run this code, I got an error that says:

ORA-06550: line 4, column 37:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following:

what is the mistake?
Thanks

Comment: Did you actually read the error message? It tells you exactly what's wrong - you have the symbol `&` where it's not supposed to be. As far as how to fix it, you didn't show us what `show_desc` or `sv_cnumber` is, so it's pretty difficult to say what's wrong. "My car makes a funny noise. I'm not going to tell you what it sounds like or where it's coming from, though. What's wrong with it?"

Comment: where did `sv_cnumber` come from?

Comment: now the function is put on, what I want is to enter the course id, what the function does is to return the description of the course

Comment: You want a prompt to be shown so you can enter the course id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a prompt to be displayed so you can enter a value for the variable, try replacing & with colon

```
v_desc:=show_desc(:sv_cnumber);
```

`&` is a [special symbol](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=621872) in PL/SQL